why my shell script generates zombies and sometimes works weird
I have a simple script for the i3 window manager that shows an i3bar at the bottom of the screen when you touch its edge with the mouse. It almost always works fine. However, after it quits, there is always a zombie process. And the more this script is called, the more zombies there are.
Also, for some unknown reason, the script sometimes either does not work at all, or works with a long delay.
# i3 config:
# exec --no-startup-id xdotool behave_screen_edge --quiesce 300 bottom exec ~/.config/i3blocks/bar-toggle.sh

# shows bar
i3-msg bar hidden_state show

CURSOR_STILL_NEAR_BOTTOM=1

# We want bar to stay open until cursor moves away from its top edge
TOP_OF_BOTTOM_EDGE=735

while [ "$CURSOR_STILL_NEAR_BOTTOM" -eq 1 ];
do
    eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
    if [ "$Y" -lt "$TOP_OF_BOTTOM_EDGE" ]; then
        CURSOR_STILL_NEAR_BOTTOM=0
    else
        # time before panel hides
        sleep 0.5
    fi
done

# hides bar
i3-msg bar hidden_state hide

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Everything is running in Virtualbox 7.0 (Debian 12 testing installed)

(1) How do you run (invoke) the script?   (2) What do you mean by “does not work at all”?   (3) What do you mean by “a long delay”? 0.6 seconds? 60 seconds?   (4) Can you describe “[it] works with a long delay” better?   (5) Have you tried debugging the script (e.g., by adding logging)?   (6) What processes are becoming zombies?

You might occasionally be running the script twice or more simultaneously, if you move the mouse up enough that xdotool looks for a new edge detect, but your script is still doing the sleep 0.5. Try using ...bottom exec --sync ... to wait for the script to finish, or use flock in the script to lock a file while it runs, and do nothing if the lock is already taken.

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' (1) It run from i3 config file exec --no-startup-id xdotool behave_screen_edge --delay 200 --quiesce 200 bottom exec ~/.config/i3blocks/bar-toggle.sh (2) It just doesn't run. There is no such process and no bar when I touch bottom of the screen (3) About 3-5 sec (5) No (6) bar-toggle.sh

@meuh With option --sync it just doesn't start at all

There is an issue open for exec leaving zombies, from 2016. A user has provided a fix. You would need to recompile from the sources to apply it.

@meuh Thanks a lot! Thought it was my mistake...

There is an open
issue from 2016 for
xdotool exec leaving zombies. A fix is provided that needs you to
recompile the sources.
An alternative is to use exec --sync, since this waits for the child
process to exit, and so leaves no zombies. However, this also seems to
perturb the working of the "behave" loop waiting for X11 events, and
sometimes there is a long delay before the edge detection works again.
A solution seems to be to use
exec --sync sh -c 'bar-toggle.sh &'

This makes the shell return immediately, but the child target "bar-toggle"
script continues running normally in the background. There is still no
zombie left.
The problem is now that the edge detection can activate again immediately,
and exec a new "bar-toggle" whilst the old one is still running.
One way to avoid this is to use flock to lock a file whilst running the
script. The usage is: flock <lockfile> <command-to-run>.
A suitable file to lock is simply the script itself.
So you have: flock bar-toggle.sh bar-toggle.sh
The flock option -w 0 sets a 0 timeout to wait. If you cannot immediately
lock the file, the command is not run. The final result is:
xdotool behave_screen_edge --quiesce 300 bottom exec --sync sh -c '
 flock -w 0 ~/.config/i3blocks/bar-toggle.sh \
            ~/.config/i3blocks/bar-toggle.sh & '


Well, thank you all for feedback!
The solution proposed by @meuh is working. There is no more zombies. However, the strange bug did not disappear. Sometimes the script simply refused to work for no apparent reason. So I decided to completely get rid of xdotool behave_screen_edge and replace it with xdotool getmouselocation.
Just in case, I am posting the final version of the script here. It works perfectly.
Thanks again to everyone!
# i3 config: exec --no-startup-id ~/.config/i3blocks/bar-toggle.sh
VISIBLE=0
TOP=735     # Y coordinate of upper bar's margin
BOTTOM=766  # Y coordinate to show bar (could be little less then bottom of screen to shorten delay before bar becomes visible)
PAUSE_HIDE=0.5  # pause before hiding bar
PAUSE_SHOW=0.3  # pause between loops. too short can load your cpu, too long - delay before bar becomes visible
while true
do
    # get cursor coordinates
    eval $( xdotool getmouselocation --shell )
    if [ "$VISIBLE" -eq 0 ]; then
        # bar hidden, let's check if we need to show it
        if [ "$Y" -ge "$BOTTOM" ]; then
            VISIBLE=1
            i3-msg -q bar hidden_state show
        fi
    else
        # bar visible, let's check if we need to hide it
        if [ "$Y" -lt "$TOP" ]; then
            VISIBLE=0
            sleep $PAUSE_HIDE
            i3-msg -q bar hidden_state hide
        fi
    fi
    sleep $PAUSE_SHOW
done;


"Zombies" are created when a child procesd exit()s, and the parent process doesn't collect the child's exit status with wait(), and the system can't finish cleaning up the child process' task. If the parent process exit()s before doing so, the resources are truly lost. In either case, the child task "lives" on as a zombie.
The only child process creation is your xdotool invocation.
Harvest the xdotool status, and throw it away:
eval "$(xdotool getmouselocation --shell;echo $?>/dev/null)"

Always paste your script into https://shellcheck.net, a syntax checker, or install shellcheck locally. Make using shellcheck part of your development process.

(1a) Why do you believe that eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell) could leave a zombie, or that your version would prevent one?  (1b) Your suggestion has mismatched quotes.  (2) I’m guessing that the OP is running the script asynchronously, and that the zombie is the shell process — that’s why I asked how they run (invoke) the script.

echo $?>/dev/null doesn't help. Nothing changes.

While the wording in POSIX Shell Introduction is "The shell optionally waits for the command to complete and collects the exit status", in practice most shells execute some form of wait(2) on synchronous execution (ie. not using & to background a process). Exit status $? is literally the return value of wait(2). So echo $?>/dev/null is superfluous.

“If the parent process exit()s before doing so, the resources are truly lost” — no, if the parent exits, the zombie is reparented to init which periodically reaps child processes.
